# How to resolve jQuery conflict

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a few lines of jQuery codes that load external pages when the links are clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();      
    var $urlToLoad = $(this).attr('href'); 

    $("#loadarea").load($urlToLoad, function(data){
        $("#loading").fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast');
        $("#loadarea").hide().fadeIn('slow');       
        return false;
        });
    });      


});
```

This works fine. However, when I add this one single line of additional code, which is essential on this page, "$ is undefined" error shows up.

I've tried every single technique at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ but, I can't resolve the conflict.

```
function goto(id, t){   
    $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);
    $('#slide a').removeClass('active');
    $(t).addClass('active');    
}
```

I've tried var jq=jQuery.noConflict();  to replace $ but this doesn't solve the problem.

I guess I do not understand enough of jQuery to resolve this conflict and I would really appreciate anyone who can explain what is going on so that I can learn from this.

So all together, it looks like this:

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();      
    var $urlToLoad = $(this).attr('href'); 

    $("#loadarea").load($urlToLoad, function(data){
        $("#loading").fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast');
        $("#loadarea").hide().fadeIn('slow');       
        return false;
        });
    });      


}); 

function goto(id, t){   
    $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);
    $('#slide a').removeClass('active');
    $(t).addClass('active');    
}


</script>
```

Then I have one inline code to fire the script.

(a class="active" href="#" onClick="goto('#kr', this); return false">test

Strange thing is, that even with the error, it fires on second click.

/////////////////////////////////////

The conflict/error was resolved by converting the inline javascript.

Thanks to Huangism below.

Comment: Do you have a live URL that can be seen?

Comment: where did you add this function? usually undefined meaning jquery file is not called or your function was used before the file was called

Comment: I am using them together within <script> </script>.  They are not separate; I've separated it to clearly show which line is causing the conflict.

Comment: @Matthew - post that script tag here, for surely you are using seperate script tags for jQuery and your inline code ?

Comment: <li ><a class="active" href="#" onClick="goto('#kr', this); return false">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="goto('#en', this); return false">test</a></li>

Comment: I would suggest you remove the inline onclick and use jquery to handle the click event using .on. It almost looks like a racing issue

Comment: So what element has the `.link` class again ???

Comment: show your html, including .link part

Comment: That's where I am at. But how do I go about doing that? How can I change <a class="active" href="#" onClick="goto('#kr', this); return false">test</a> to be included in the above code?

Comment: take a look at my answer for the jquery rewrite of your goto function

Answer (score 1):

I would just rewrite the anchor from

```
<a class="active" href="#" onClick="goto('#kr', this); return false">test</a>
```

To

```
<a class="active" href="#kr">test</a>
```

For the jquery

```
$('.active').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);        
    var id = $this.attr('href');
    $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);
    $('#slide a').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  So I guess I learned something new today.  Inline javascript is bad.  I need to study this little more but a great big thanks.

Comment: How can I choose this reply as "the answer" btw? Or is there no such thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Should be rewritten as:

```
jQuery(function($) {

});
```

That might help you out here.

Comment: As stated above, I tried every method mentioned in jQuery noConflict API page.  I had tried this already; I wouldn't be asking a question here if I haven't tried every common method known.

I have a great respect for Stack Overflow; I wouldn't post a question before I try to solve the problem first.

Comment: Meanwhile this answer just TOTALLY worked for me, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to do with the order that you're including your js files in, make sure that jquery is the first loaded file.